# How can I stream PC desktop, 1:1 pixel ratio, to Android device?

Tags: streaming

Does anyone have a solution for streaming pc screen content to an Android device with 1:1 pixel ratio? I want to use it to display graphical work directly on the device, and possible for the future to produce quick interactive prototypes.

There is an application for iOS called [LiveView](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/liveview/id301069270?mt=8) which lets you bring up a container on your Mac which streams the content of the container straight to your iOS device.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of any solution for Android that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [SplashTop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.splashtop.remote.pad.v2) Desktop Streaming Application. The app is free, but has some in-app purchases for more features.

They also have a few [premium versions available](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Splashtop).

Comment: +1 I really like the looks of this. However, I'm not getting it to work. I created an account using the app and then downloaded the PC client. When I tried logging into the PC client it said that there was no account with that email... really weird. so I created the same account again in the PC client, which did go through. But the PC client still doesn't recognize the device. so frustrating, I wonder where it went wrong...

Comment: It has been a while since I used it (and set it up). I will try when I get home, unless you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

http://betanews.com/2012/01/05/turn-you-android-into-a-second-pc-monitor/

try this.
hope it will help you,
cheers

Comment: Please add some more information to your answer. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/156683

Answer (score 0):

There is screen stream for Android that seems to do what you are asking.
It streams live the display of the device and has many options.
There is a trial version here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobzapp.screenstream.trial